# How to pass custom parameters in statusCallback Twilio voice outbound call c# & then get it in callback method. Please suggest

Tags: twilio, outbound

I need track statusCallbackEvent when call answered, completed, also need to pass StatusCallback with custom parameter please suggest how to achieve it?

my code is something like

```
 public CallResource MakeOutboundPhoneCallsAsync(OutgoingCallRequest request, string accountSid, string authToken)
        {
            try
            {
                TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
                List<string> statusCallbackEvent = new List<string> { "answered", "completed" };
                CallResource response =
                    CallResource.Create(
                                url: new Uri("http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"),
                                to: new PhoneNumber(request.ToPhoneNumber),
                                from: new PhoneNumber(request.FromPhoneNumber),
                                method: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Get,
                                statusCallback: new Uri("http://b28deaf4.ngrok.io/api/Twilio/OutboundCalls/StatusCallback"),
                                statusCallbackEvent: statusCallbackEvent,
                                statusCallbackMethod: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Post
                            );

                return response;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you want to pass more parameters back to your application via the webhook, you can do so by including query parameters in the URL. For example:

```
statusCallback: new Uri("http://b28deaf4.ngrok.io/api/Twilio/OutboundCalls/StatusCallback?ExtraParameter=InTheQueryString"),
```

Then you can read them out of the URL when your application receives the request.

Comment: I have already tried like this but my callback not hitting, can you please provide me the sample of callback method.

Comment: Are you saying that you aren't receiving status callback webhooks at all? Have you ensured you keep your ngrok URL up to date as that changes with each time you restart ngrok?

Comment: Yes, my ngrok is up to date, now it is also hitting callback method but the parameters i have specified in my callback method getting null values (public IActionResult StatusCallback(string Called, string ToState,....), please suggest

Comment: Custom parameters working prefect but null value issue with parameters that returned from Twilio like CallSid, CallStatus, CallDuration etc. Please suggest for it.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it all sorted!